# wrong count when joining 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

so there is a online betting website , i want to count each user bets and wins (his selected options that are right/winner not winning bets -> each bet may have lots of options  )

here is simplified structure of my tables

```
users            : id  , username , email 
user_bets        : id  , user_id  , date , amount
user_bets_options: id  , bet_id   , user_id  , status
```

here is my query  , basically it gets a user , counts his bets and counts his winning choices from 3rd table

```
SELECT `users`.*,     
  count(`user_bets`.`id`) as bets,    
  count(`user_bets_options`.`id`) as wins    
FROM `users`     
LEFT JOIN `user_bets` ON `user_bets`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`    
LEFT JOIN `user_bets_options` ON `user_bets_options`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
                              and `user_bets_options`.`status` = 1     
WHERE `email` = 'mymail@yahoo.com'     
GROUP BY `users`.`id` LIMIT 10
```

so if i count   wins and bets separately (joining users table with each separately ) , this user has about 94 bets and 53 wins which is about right

but when i count using above query and join all 3 table together both would be 4982 !

Comment: You're getting a cartesian product because of your left joins.  I would think they would need to be inner joins wouldnt they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try joining on bet_id instead of user_id when joining to user_bet_options.
Then the win count should be correct.

Comment: thanx , dont know why but this did it (i mean i dont know why the last one didn't work !)

Comment: Joining on user_id both places give one result row for each combination of bet and win (for each user) whether related or not. Joining on bet_id is needed in order to include only rows in which the win is related to the bet.

Answer (score 0):

Try count(distinct --column_name--). Putting only a column name in a count does nothing special for that column, it only counts how many rows there are within the same GROUP. But this isn't something with a good performance. But that would still be wrong as the users with no bets or wins would still show at least 1.

Another better would be:

```
SELECT 'users',*,
       (
         SELECT
                COUNT(1)
         FROM
                'user_bets'
         WHERE
                'user_bets'.'user_id' = 'users','id'
       ) BETS,
       (
         SELECT
                 COUNT(1)
         FROM
                 'user_bets_options'
         WHERE
                 'user_bets_options','user_id' = 'users'.'id'
         AND     'user_bets_options'.'status' = 1
       ) WINS
FROM
       'users'
WHERE 
       `email` = 'mymail@yahoo.com'
LIMIT  10
```